# How to use R's xtable() to print the output of table() and keep the row and column margin titles? and rotate

Tags: tables, r

I need to generate many small tables from different pairs of vectors like this:   (the vectors have names of different lengths)

```
library(xtable)
input1 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
input2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2)
result <- table(input1, input2)
xtable(result)
   or 
print(xtable(x), include.rownames=T, include.colnames=T)
```

The console output is OK.

> result

```
       input2
input1 0 1 2
     0 3 0 0
     1 3 1 0
     2 2 1 1
```

But I'd like to get a nice latex output instead.
xtable produces this code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  \hline
 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  \hline
  0 &   3 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  1 &   3 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  2 &   2 &   1 &   1 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see the "input1" and "input2" margin titles have dissapeared.
[image]

But I'd like to get something like this: (or with more lines if you think it looks nicer).
[image]

What command do I need to use in R in order to get it?

I've found a solution that at least shows the names, but not in a beautiful way:

```
print(xtable(format(ftable(result))), include.rownames=FALSE, include.colnames=FALSE, sanitize.text.function = function(x) {gsub('"',"",x)})

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
  \hline
  \hline
         & input2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  input1 &          &     &     &     \\ 
  0      &          &   3 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  1      &          &   3 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  2      &          &   2 &   1 &   1 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

with this method the separation of the left column will depend on the length of its title. I would prefer to have the left title rotated and placed to the left, and the other one on the top.

I need to know how to programatically modify the generated LaTeX output from R.

Answer (score 4):

Force the dinnames of a R `table()` to a multicolumn and a rotated multirow seem not trivial for me, so this is not what you ask, but maybe worth show some an alternative format. I think that the obtained with `xtableFtable` is even more understandable:

```
tbl <-ftable(result,row.vars=c(1,2))
xftbl <- xtableFtable(tbl, method = "compact")
print.xtableFtable(xftbl, booktabs = T)
```

[image: mwe1]

Some others ...

[image: mwe]

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage{diagbox}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{multicol}
---
\parskip1em\centering

```{r, echo=F,results='asis',warning=F,message=F}
library(xtable)
input1 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
input2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2)
result <- table(input1, input2)
result1 <- data.frame(input1, input2)
options(omitlatexcom=T,xtable.comment=F,xtable.floating=F)
```


```{r, echo=F,results='asis',warning=F,message=F}
Hmisc::latex(result,comment=F,rowlabel="\\diagbox{input1}{input2}",  file="") 
```

```{r, echo=F,results='asis',warning=F,message=F}
xtableFtable(ftable(result1)) 
```


```{r, echo=F,results='asis',warning=F,message=F}
tbl <-ftable(result)
xftbl <- xtableFtable(tbl, method = "compact")
print.xtableFtable(xftbl, booktabs = F)
```

```{r, echo=F,results='asis',warning=F,message=F}
tbl <-ftable(result,row.vars=c(1,2))
xftbl <- xtableFtable(tbl, method = "compact")
print.xtableFtable(xftbl, booktabs = T, rotate.rownames = T)
```

```{r, echo=F,results='asis',warning=F,message=F}
x <- as.data.frame(result)
knitr::kable(x)
```

```{r, echo=F,results='asis',warning=F,message=F}
x <- format(ftable(result))
# knitr::kable(x)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

With appropriate use of `\multirow`  and `\multicolumn` you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow} % For the multirow command
\usepackage{graphicx} % For the rotatebox command 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|lll}
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{input2}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  &   0 &   1 &   2 \\  
    \cline{3-5}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{input1}}  & 0 &   3 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  & 1 &   3 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  & 2 &   2 &   1 &   1 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With `\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{0.75\tabcolsep}}l|lll}` the spacing is tighter:

[image]

Comment: But i don't mean writing the code by hand on the latex editor but getting it directly from R.  Maybe doing it in general could be difficult, we could particularize it for a given dimension, for example 3x3 tables.

Comment: @skan: Sorry for this misundestanding. Maybe you can find something more useful here: [possible to create latex multicolumns in xtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13984470)

Comment: Another simple question. How can I get the input1 label a little bit closer to the table? (more to the right)

Comment: @skan: I've updated my answer on that.

Comment: Yesterday I was tryong myself and ended up using \begin{tabular}{p{1ex}l|rrr}  What is better? My problem was that some tables use large titles and I had to use \thead{verylong\\titleforme}  So some are one line, some two and I have to adjust the width manually to get a uniform visual effect.

Comment: @skan: With `\begin{tabular}{l@{}l|lll}
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{input2}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  &   0 &   1 &   2 \\  
    \cline{3-5}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\thead{input1\\ more\\ text}}}  & 0 &   3 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  & 1 &   3 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  & 2 &   2 &   1 &   1 \\ 
\end{tabular}` you get https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyYXG.png without the need to manually adjust the width of the respective column.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed above (example for a student table).

With R

```
library(Hmisc)
n <-seq(1,10,by=1)
alpha <- c(0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01,0.001)
mt<-outer(n,alpha, function(n,alpha) round(qt(1-alpha/2,n),2) )
colnames(mt)<-alpha
rownames(mt)<-n
Hmisc::latex(mt,comment=F,rowlabel="\\diagbox{$\\nu$}{$\\alpha$}",  file="")
```

This gives the following **result** (in R):

```
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrr}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\diagbox{$\nu$}{$\alpha$}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.5}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.4}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.05}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.02}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.01}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.001}\tabularnewline
\hline
1&$1.00$&$1.38$&$1.96$&$3.08$&$6.31$&$12.71$&$31.82$&$63.66$&$636.62$\tabularnewline
2&$0.82$&$1.06$&$1.39$&$1.89$&$2.92$&$ 4.30$&$ 6.96$&$ 9.92$&$ 31.60$\tabularnewline
3&$0.76$&$0.98$&$1.25$&$1.64$&$2.35$&$ 3.18$&$ 4.54$&$ 5.84$&$ 12.92$\tabularnewline
4&$0.74$&$0.94$&$1.19$&$1.53$&$2.13$&$ 2.78$&$ 3.75$&$ 4.60$&$  8.61$\tabularnewline
5&$0.73$&$0.92$&$1.16$&$1.48$&$2.02$&$ 2.57$&$ 3.36$&$ 4.03$&$  6.87$\tabularnewline
6&$0.72$&$0.91$&$1.13$&$1.44$&$1.94$&$ 2.45$&$ 3.14$&$ 3.71$&$  5.96$\tabularnewline
7&$0.71$&$0.90$&$1.12$&$1.41$&$1.89$&$ 2.36$&$ 3.00$&$ 3.50$&$  5.41$\tabularnewline
8&$0.71$&$0.89$&$1.11$&$1.40$&$1.86$&$ 2.31$&$ 2.90$&$ 3.36$&$  5.04$\tabularnewline
9&$0.70$&$0.88$&$1.10$&$1.38$&$1.83$&$ 2.26$&$ 2.82$&$ 3.25$&$  4.78$\tabularnewline
10&$0.70$&$0.88$&$1.09$&$1.37$&$1.81$&$ 2.23$&$ 2.76$&$ 3.17$&$  4.59$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Put the **result** in LaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\begin{document}
% result here
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrr}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\diagbox{$\nu$}{$\alpha$}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.5}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.4}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.05}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.02}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.01}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.001}\tabularnewline
\hline
1&$1.00$&$1.38$&$1.96$&$3.08$&$6.31$&$12.71$&$31.82$&$63.66$&$636.62$\tabularnewline
2&$0.82$&$1.06$&$1.39$&$1.89$&$2.92$&$ 4.30$&$ 6.96$&$ 9.92$&$ 31.60$\tabularnewline
3&$0.76$&$0.98$&$1.25$&$1.64$&$2.35$&$ 3.18$&$ 4.54$&$ 5.84$&$ 12.92$\tabularnewline
4&$0.74$&$0.94$&$1.19$&$1.53$&$2.13$&$ 2.78$&$ 3.75$&$ 4.60$&$  8.61$\tabularnewline
5&$0.73$&$0.92$&$1.16$&$1.48$&$2.02$&$ 2.57$&$ 3.36$&$ 4.03$&$  6.87$\tabularnewline
6&$0.72$&$0.91$&$1.13$&$1.44$&$1.94$&$ 2.45$&$ 3.14$&$ 3.71$&$  5.96$\tabularnewline
7&$0.71$&$0.90$&$1.12$&$1.41$&$1.89$&$ 2.36$&$ 3.00$&$ 3.50$&$  5.41$\tabularnewline
8&$0.71$&$0.89$&$1.11$&$1.40$&$1.86$&$ 2.31$&$ 2.90$&$ 3.36$&$  5.04$\tabularnewline
9&$0.70$&$0.88$&$1.10$&$1.38$&$1.83$&$ 2.26$&$ 2.82$&$ 3.25$&$  4.78$\tabularnewline
10&$0.70$&$0.88$&$1.09$&$1.37$&$1.81$&$ 2.23$&$ 2.76$&$ 3.17$&$  4.59$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE!  I would suggest you include what you label as the "result" in your answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the advice.